# ¿Como volver a un punto en python?

Tags: python, bucles, validationerror

busco que a la hora que el usuario ponga un valor distinto a 1,2 o 3, lo regrese a escoger una opcion, ya que de esta forma el programa se cierra. Sot nuevo y ando practicando.
Lo intente con un ciclo while pero no entendi muy bien como

```
import string as str, secrets as sc, crypt as cr

lower = str.ascii_lowercase
upper = str.ascii_uppercase
numbers = str.digits
special_characters = str.punctuation
alphabet = lower+upper+numbers+special_characters

pwd_length = int(input("Choose the length of the password: "))
pwd = ""
for i in range(pwd_length):
 pwd += "".join(sc.choice(alphabet))
 encrypted_pwd ="".join(cr.crypt(pwd)) 

menu = """
1: Show only the password in plain text
2: Show only the encrypted password
3: Show both
"""
choose = int(input(menu))

if choose == 1:
 print(f"Your password is: {pwd}")

elif choose == 2:
 print(encrypted_pwd)
 print(f"Your password is: {encrypted_pwd}")

elif choose == 3:
 print(pwd,encrypted_pwd)
 print(f"Your encrypted password is: {encrypted_pwd} and your plain text password is: {pwd}")

else:
 print("I dont understand, please try again")
```

Comment: ¿Desde donde se debería repetir? ¿Desde `choose = ...`, `pwd_length = ...` o dónde?

Comment: desde choose, es el punto en el cual le debera de preguntar otra vez que ingresa una opcion entre 1 y 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El ciclo `while` funciona de esta manera:

Escribes `while` seguido de la condición a evaluar, dos puntos y en las siguientes líneas las instrucciones que se deben repetir (como con el if solo que en ese caso no se repiten).

Por ejemplo:

```
// Escribe los números del 0 al 10
num = 0
while num <= 10:
    print(num)
    num += 1
```

Una de las maneras en que puedes aplicarlo a tu código es esta:

```
while True: 
     choose = int(input(menu))
    
   if choose == 1:
     print(f"Your password is: {pwd}")
     break
    
   elif choose == 2:
     print(encrypted_pwd)
     print(f"Your password is: {encrypted_pwd}")
     break
    
   elif choose == 3:
     print(pwd,encrypted_pwd)
     print(f"Your encrypted password is: {encrypted_pwd} and your plain text password is: {pwd}")
     break
    
   else:
     print("I dont understand, please try again")
```

En este caso de condición decidí que se repita siempre (la condición es `True`). Entonces puedo detener el ciclo con la instrucción `break`. Que está en los primeros 3 if.

Comment: en efecto, asi quedo muchas gracias. Sin embargo tengo otra duda. ¿para enviar esto a Github debe de haber buenas practicas, te puedo proporcionar el link del repositorio y me puedes dar tu opinion:?

Comment: de ser el caso, te comparo el link: https://github.com/danielpzu

Answer (score 1):

Leí tu pregunta y veo que eres nuevo en este mundillo. Intentaste emplear un bucle `while` sin éxito, por lo que te recomendaré [esta entrada](https://www.ionos.es/digitalguide/paginas-web/desarrollo-web/bucle-while-de-python/#:%7E:text=El%20bucle%20while%20de%20Python,no%20viene%20determinado%20de%20antemano.) y te ilustraré un poco.

Tienes un menú que admite una elección de `1` a `3`, por lo que cualquier valor fuera de este rango se considera inválido, como por ejemplo `0`. Si deseas usar `choose` en un bucle, es importante declararla primero, ya que si no, al colocarla dentro del bucle, obtendrás un error sobre que intentaste usar una variable antes de declararla.

```
choose = 0

while choose < 1 or choose > 3:
    choose = int(input(menu))
```

El bucle evalúa `choose` y ve que su valor es `0`. Esto cumple la condición, ya que `0` es menor que `1` y el bucle inicia. Ahora `choose` pasa a contener la entrada del usuario y bueno, si el usuario ingresa algo diferente de `1`, `2` o `3` entonces la condición `choose < 1 or choose > 3` siempre se cumple, haciendo que el bucle provoque de se repita la instrucción `input`. Y, no es necesario colocar la declaración de `menu` en el bucle, ya que no necesitas volver a declararla, solo leerla para mostrarla al usuario cada vez que le pides el valor.

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias!